# how to debug ReadP parser?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I've written a simple parser using [readP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html). it works, but I'm using it as a sort of validating parser, as input is manually written and sometimes deviates from norm. in order to correct the input, I'd like to know in which line my parser failed, so my question is:

how can I obtain a debugging message showing in which line of input my parser failed, like the ones shown in [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) (for Parsec)?

(I'm fairly new to haskell, btw.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReadP` doesn't offer error-reporting capabilities. That's evident from the type of a `ReadP` parser:

```
newtype ReadP a = R (forall b . (a -> P b) -> P b)
data P a
  = Get (Char -> P a)
  | Look (String -> P a)
  | Fail
  | Result a (P a)
  | Final [(a,String)] -- invariant: list is non-empty!
  deriving Functor
```

You can see that the `Fail` constructor doesn't store any information.

You will need to use a different parser combinator library for that (or build your own).

Comment: hum, ok! thanks for showing me how to find the answer, I'll keep that in mind :)